# Xaml How to Enable/Disable and Validate text item in one time

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, devexpress-wpf

Using MVVM, Devexpress WPF, c#

For example I have two items in a view (I have more in real project) and using them for user to enter some search paramaters and need to validate them and the same time disable another one, if something is written in the first field and overwise.

What I do, I use Validate to determ the Lenght of value and I need to Enable/Disable even if lenght of entered text doesn't meet required lenght

**View**
Xaml:

```
<dxe:TextEdit

  Text="{Binding SearchField1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  Validate="searchFieldValidate"/>

<dxe:TextEdit
      IsEnabled="{Binding IsTextItemEnabled}"
      Text="{Binding SearchField2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      Validate="searchFieldValidate"/>
```

c#

```
private void searchFieldValidate(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Value == null) return;
            if (e.Value.ToString().Length > 5) return;
            e.IsValid = false;
            e.ErrorType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ErrorType.Warning;
            e.ErrorContent = "Enter more than 5 symbol";
        }
```

**ViewModel**
Here I set IsTextItemEnabled depending on is value empty or mot

```
public string SearchField1
        {
            get { return _searchField1; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _searchField1)
                {
                    _searchField1 = value;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                        IsTextItemEnabled = false;
                    else
                        IsTextItemEnabled = true;

                    RaisePropertiesChanged("SearchField1");
                }
            }
        }
```

A problem is that RaisePropertiesChanged doesn't work until field lenght doesn't reach 5 symbols

Could You please help me to solve this problem? First of all I am trying to Disable one field, so I use one bool IsTextEnabled.. what about oposite variant...

Answer (score 0):

I gave names to TextEdit

```
<dxe:TextEdit
 Name="txtEdit1"
 Text="{Binding SearchField1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 Validate="searchFieldValidate"/>

<dxe:TextEdit
 Name="txtEdit2"
 Text="{Binding SearchField2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

and add a line to validate procedure:

```
txtEdit2.IsEnabled = String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value?.ToString());
```

So now I am able to validate and enable/disable at one time.. Don't use OnPropertiesChanged this time